# Use BorderLayout to create two even columns

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I'm trying to create a program using BorderLayout() that I want to look like this (but with even left right height and such)

[image]

although I am having trouble resizing the two JPanels (two boxes within the large box). At the moment my GUI looks like this,

[image]

I believe it is due to the CENTER still being there, I looked up on how to remove it but could not get it to work,

**Question**

Can can I edit this so that it will look like the top image.

```
package fuelstation;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Fuelstation extends JFrame {


    JButton btn1 = new JButton("Random Button");


    public Fuelstation() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fuel Station");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,350));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,350));

//        Left Hand Side
        JPanel lhs = new JPanel();
        JTextArea tf_list = new JTextArea();
        tf_list.setEditable(false);
        tf_list.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        tf_list.setText("This is a list of items");
        lhs.add(tf_list);
        tf_list.setSize(245, 325);
        lhs.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Left"));
//        Left Hand Side End


//        Right Hand Side
        JPanel rhs = new JPanel();
        rhs.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        rhs.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Right"));
        rhs.add(btn1);
        tf_list.setSize(245, 325);

        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setSize(0, 0);
//        Right Hand Side End

        frame.add(lhs, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(rhs, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fuelstation gui = new Fuelstation();
    }

}
```

Comment: What about using a `GridLayout` with 1 row and 2 columns?

Comment: Why the center? Do you have to have the center? Cuz I think that's what's screwing you up. That JPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to drop the requirement to use a `BorderLayout`. The resizing policy for components when using a `BorderLayout` is stated in the [class javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)

> The components are laid out according to their preferred sizes and the constraints of the container's size. The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally; the EAST and WEST components may be stretched vertically; the CENTER component may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left over.

By forcing your `JFrame` to a certain size

```
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,350));
frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,350));
```

your center component will take the extra width, as the `EAST` and `WEST` component will only stretch vertically.

So you need to use another `LayoutManager`. You can use the [Visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to get a grasp of the available `LayoutManager`s and their capabilities. That document states that a `GridLayout` would be a good candidate:

> GridLayout simply makes a bunch of components equal in size and displays them in the requested number of rows and columns

Comment: @jackdh For your simple case one `LayoutManager` is sufficient. However for more complex layouts you will often end up mixing different layout managers. See [this excellent example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/1076463)